# Can preg_split be used to split a string into an array while also removing any whitespace?

Tags: php, regex

Is there some regular expression that will ignore all spaces while splitting on all other characters?

```
$phrase = 'asdf asdf';
$result = preg_split('//', $phrase, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "s"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "d"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "f"
  [4]=>
  string(1) " " // this should be excluded
  [5]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "s"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "d"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "f"
}
```

Comment: Filter result array.

Comment: This question is asking whether it's possible to use `preg_split` to do both actions in one step. If it's not possible, that's an acceptable answer.

Comment: This expression you have will do a poor job on multibyte chars. You do not want to fix this approach. Use matching. Something like `preg_match_all('~\X(?<!\s)~u', $s, $m)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's a great answer. Please formalize it with an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to split a string into characters with a regex avoiding whitespaces in the result, it is safer to use a matching approach:

```
if (preg_match_all('~\X(?<!\s)~u', $s, $m)) {
    print_r($m[0]);
}
```

The `~\X(?<!\s)~u` expression matches any Unicode "grapheme" but not if this is a whitespace.

See [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/IgOf8):

```
$s = "प्रमुख समाचार";
if (preg_match_all('~\X(?<!\s)~u', $s, $m)) {
    print_r($m[0]);
} // => Array ( [0] => प् [1] => र [2] => मु [3] => ख [4] => स [5] => मा [6] => चा  [7] => र )
```